# Dequeue implementation removes all records instead of the front record?

Tags: c++, queue

Im trying to implement a dequeuing program that reads a file and adds records to a queue

my program can be seen below

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>


#define SIZE 500
std::string fileName;
const int serverSize = 20;
int A[SIZE];
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;

struct passengerData
{
    double arrivalTime;
    int passengerClass;
    double serviceClass;
};

bool isEmpty()
{
 if(front == -1 && rear == -1)
 return true;
 else
 return false;
}

void enqueue ( int value )
{

 if (rear == SIZE-1)
  std::cout<<"Queue is full \n";
 else
 {
  if( front == -1)
   front = 0;
  rear++;
  A[rear] = value;
 }
}

void dequeue ( )
{
 if( isEmpty() )
  std::cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
 else
 if( front == rear )
  front = rear = -1;
 else
  front++;
}

void showFront()
{
 if( isEmpty())
  std::cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
 else
  std::cout<<"Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : "<< A[front]<<"\n";
}

void displayQueue()
{
 if(isEmpty())
  std::cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
 else
 {

  for( int i=front; i<=rear; i++)
   std::cout<<A[i]<<" ";
   std::cout<<"\n";
 }
}

std::vector<passengerData>displayData(std::string fileName) {

  std::vector<passengerData> result;
  std::ifstream file(fileName);
  passengerData data;
  double totalTime;

     while (file >> data.arrivalTime >> data.passengerClass >> data.serviceClass) 
     result.push_back(data);
     return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the file: " << std::endl; //prompts user for the filename
    std::cin >> fileName;
   
   for(auto &&i: displayData(fileName)) {
      enqueue(i.arrivalTime); 
      std::cout << "Passenger with arrival time " << i.arrivalTime << " has entered the queue" << std::endl; 

      showFront();
      dequeue();

      std::cout << "Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: " << i.arrivalTime << std::endl;
      showFront();
   }

  
    return 0;
}
```

When testing the program when reading 5 records in a text file like such

```
2.7388 0 2.4670
3.6384 1 24.5927
8.7844 0 10.6871
11.2892 0 2.6507
19.6054 1 16.8974
```

The following output is produced

```
Passenger with arrival time 2.7388 has entered the queue
Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : 2
Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: 2.7388
Queue is empty
Passenger with arrival time 3.6384 has entered the queue
Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : 3
Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: 3.6384
Queue is empty
Passenger with arrival time 8.7844 has entered the queue
Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : 8
Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: 8.7844
Queue is empty
Passenger with arrival time 11.2892 has entered the queue
Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : 11
Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: 11.2892
Queue is empty
Passenger with arrival time 19.6054 has entered the queue
Passenger at front of queue with arrival time of : 19
Passenger at front after dequeue with arrival time: 19.6054
Queue is empty
```

From my understanding of queues and the output I recieve, the records are added to the queue through the `enqeue()` function where the first passenger is displayed using the `showFront()` function. The front value is then removed through `dequeue()`. From my output you can see that as each record is being queued, and the following dequeue function is called the queue is being returded as empty. From my output you can also see the dequeue function is removing all records with one function call rather than just the record at the front. The output `queue is empty` should only be appearing once dequeue is called 5 times in this case, not once.

Ive ran test data where i enter the values to be queued manually like such

```
  enqueue(1);
  enqueue(2);
  enqueue(3);
  showFront();
  dequeue();
  dequeue();
  std::cout << "Queue after dequeue: " << std::endl;
  showFront();
```

which produces an output which is correct.

```
element at front is 1
Queue after dequeue: //which new element is at the front after dequeue 
element at front is 3
```

From comparing this output with the output i get from reading the file I believe the issue is how the file is being read/passed into the `enqueue()` function. Am I getting the incorrect output as im adding all records to the queue as such `enqueue(i.arrivalTime);`  ? or am I reading in the file incorrectly?

Thankyou

Comment: please post a [mcve]. what is `A`, `SIZE`, `front` and `rear` ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 these have been added

Comment: i added the missing includes. Please fix in case I guessed wrong

Comment: `std::cin >> argv[0]; fileName = argv[0];` Why? You have no idea how much space is allocated for `argv[0]` and you have the variable you want the name to end up in right there. This makes no sense.

Comment: "which produces an output which is correct." Details do matter. THis isnt the correct output for the example you describe. Where is "Queue after deque: " ? Why is there no output from `showQueue` ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but this looks very wrong: `std::cin >> argv[0];` and it doesn't even compile on my platform. Just use `std::cin >>  fileName` and drop all references to `argv[0]`.

Comment: Also show a simple (no fancy numbers) _minimal_ example of input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: @idclev463035818 see updated quesiton

Comment: I tried this simple test code: `enqueue(1);
  enqueue(2);
  enqueue(3);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    showFront();
    dequeue();
  }`
 and the enqueing code works as expected.

Comment: in your code you call enqueue and dequeue once per loop iteration? I can't see how the queue can be anything other than empty at the end of each iteration?

Comment: @AlanBirtles ah okay I think i see my problem now. So everytime a record is added using unqeue its removed right after using dequeue?